# Database efficiency - notifications, user preferences as separate tables or all in users table?

Tags: sql, database, processing-efficiency

As per the title, when creating a typical saas app, I currently have the following tables and questioning whether they should be all put into the users table

- users (id, password_hash, user_type, first_name, last_name, timezone, language, two_factor_auth_enabled, two_factor_auth_secret, two_factor_auth_type, etc.) - should any of these be separated out?
- notifications (marketing emails, new features, user_id, etc.)
- preferences (website font size, website theme, user_id)
- secondary email (email, verifiedAt, createdAt, user_id)
- plan (plan_name, user_id, etc.)
- historical_passwords (password_hash, createdAt, updatedAt, user_id)

I currently have all these as separate tables, but not sure if some of these should be JSON blobs or just merged into the main users table since several of these are one-to-one relationships (notifications, preferences, plan).

The others won't have a lot of data so wondering if they should be JSON blobs in the users table (secondary email, historical passwords)

What is most efficient for the database and what is typical / best practice?

Comment: There is no "the database"; each engine may have its own characteristics that make one design or the other faster or more convenient. On top of that there's whatever you're using for a client library to access things that may affect this. As far as efficiency goes, this is almost certainly the wrong thing to focus on since it's unlikely to be the bottleneck in your application, whether you do it one way or another, so use the design that makes the most sense and change it if it turns out to be necessary, or else actually test it if you're concerned.